# React: Create Elements/Tags programmatically / Create React Element from String?

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for the equivalent of creating of HTML Tags step by step (concatenating them) like below in React:

```
var result="";
result += "<div>"; 
result += "dd";
result += "</div>";
```

Something like the following, but this is not working. I tried with an array, but it did also not work...

```
function MyComponent(props) {

   var result;
   result += <div>; 
   result += "dd";
   result += </div>;   

   return result; 
}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), official example:

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

In your case:

```
function MyComponent(props) {

   var result;
   result += "<div>"; 
   result += "dd";
   result += "</div>";   

   return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: result}}></div>; 
}
```

Additionally, you can look for any [`string-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser) library for use.